# How to get ID of the image displayed as hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I get list of images and display it on razor page. Every image is a 'hyperlink'. Now I have one problem. I wan't to display image as a modal view by using 'jquery.BlockUI'. But I don't know how to send id of the image to open clicked image. Any advice?

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        string imagePath = path tp the image;
        <div style="background: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #cccccc; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-right: 3px;
            padding: 3px; width: 300px; height: 100px; float: left; overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="width: 105px; float: left;">
               <a onclick="showImageModal()"> <img  src=@imagePath/> </a>
            </div>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a container, like #image-popups and then

```
$('#image-popups a').click(function(e) { 

   e.preventDefault();

    $.blockUI({ 
        message: $(this).children('img'), 
        css: { 
            top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
            left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
            width: '400px' 
        } 
    }); 

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    });
```

And then have just have

```
<a href=@imagePath> <img  src=@imagePath/> </a>
```

for when JS fails, it will link to the image, else execute BlockUI

Comment: When I add this code when I click on image it just opens as a new page. I try to debug and it never gets in this jquery code? <div id="image-popups" style="width: 105px; float: left;">
               <a href=@imagePath > <img  src=@imagePath/> </a>
            </div>

Comment: I forgot to send update. I done it by using '.live...', "$('#divid').live('click', function(e)..." and it worked. This may be required because I read and create images dinamicly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline event handlers.
Since you tagged this question with jQuery, this is how to do it with jQuery.

First change

```
<a onclick="showImageModal()"> <img  src=@imagePath/> </a>
```

to

```
<a class="image_modal"><img src="@imagePath" /></a>
```

And then use this jQuery:

```
$('.image_modal').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the hyperlink from occuring

    showImageModal($(this).find('img').attr('src'));

});
```

Here I assume your `showImageModal` function will accept a parameter that contains the image src.

Also be aware your `<a>` will not display a pointer cursor if it doesn't have a `href` attribute. So consider adding `href="@imagePath"` as well. (this will also provide a fallback for people that don't have Javascript)